# Return from "for" in Scala is not the same as return from "for" in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java code which I want to convert to Scala one:

```
    MyClass myMethod(String str1) {
      for (Item item: items) {
        if (/* some condition */) {
          if(/* another condition */) {
            return item.myMethod123();
          }
        }
     }

     return super.myMethod(str1);   
   }
```

If I use `for` in Scala, it will be translated to `map`, that is calling `return` within `map` will just return value from `map`, but it won't stop `myMethod` execution. But I want it to behave exactly like it does in this Java code.

How do I solve this?

**UPDATE**: I mean, I have to use `foreach` instead of `for`. However, calling `return` from `foreach` is just returning value from `foreach` and not stopping `myMethod` execution.

**UPDATE2**: I'm confused, `foreach` doesn't return any value.

Comment: Can you show your trial scala code?

Comment: foreach is not like java a expression, its a function on collections, which will just call a function on each item inside your map, todo like java you also need to use the for expression, like @rex-kerr explained

Comment: `items.find(item => /* some condition */ && /* another condition */).fold(super.myMethod(str1))(_.myMethod123())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It in fact *will* stop `myMethod` execution because behind the scenes it actually throws a (no-stack-trace) exception which is caught by `myMethod` before actually returning.  So you just

```
def myMethod(str1: String) {
  for (item <- items) {
    if (/*some cond*/) {
      if (/*other cond*/) {
        return item.myMethod123
      }
    }
  }
  super.myMethod(str1)
}
```

"just like" in Java.

The code works fine; it just doesn't work as fast since there is an exception involved.  (Stack traces are what take most of the time, so you're probably okay here unless it's a heavily-used loop.)

Alternatively, you can

```
val target = items.find{ item => 
  if (/* some cond */) { 
    /*other cond*/
  }
  else false
}
target.map(_.myMethod123()).getOrElse(super.myMethod(str1))
```

which will first pick out that item on which you can call a method, or will default to super if there is no such item.